# sed -e "s/-.*$//"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

What does the  -.*$/ in this command mean? Please help me decipher this.

```
echo -n full | sed -e "s/-.*$//"
```

I know what sed does and all that, I just want to know what this -.*$ part is.

Comment: Dash, followed by the rest of the line. Did you look at any documentation before coming here?

Answer (score 9):

`.` stands for any character, `*` means to match any amount (between 0 and infinite) of the previous match and `$` stands for end of line. So this sed command will match `-` followed by all characters after it until it find the end of the line and replace that with nothing, i.e. delete it.

So for example: `aajaaa-woijsdfljkwe94` becomes `aajaaa`

Also, it should be noted that `*` is 'greedy', which means it will match as many characters as possible. So, for example: `alasdf-slwddo-sdf` becomes `alasdf`, not `alasdf-slwddo`.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, this command removes everything from the first dash ('-') up to the end of the input.

Answer (score 0):

$ is the end of line regex so it reads a line with a - followed by anything on the line.

Answer (score 0):

- `.` is any character.
- `*` is "zero or more times"

Thus, `.*` is "any character, zero or more times"